# Frontend to handle course planning and administration

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, repository, n-tier

I read up on and dived into the Repository pattern for a project I am working on.
I have understood that the repository abstracts the actual access to any form of storage for my data model. What I was a bit hazy on was how to use everything in the context of an ordinary application, so I had a stab at it and came up with the following:

The application is a frontend to handle course planning and administration, much like the example given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). I want to focus on only one entity of my data model, the persons hosting a specific course. I have split my project into different libraries to encapsulate and (hopefully) better maintain different concerns.

- **DataModel**: This is the place where all my business objects live, for the scope of this question `cInstructor`
- **InterfaceProvider**: This is used only to provide the interfaces required by the business model to interact with Repositories and thus classes from the DataModel
- **DataRepositoryMySQL**: This is a concrete implementation of the interfaces defined in the InterfaceProvider and thus needs to reference it as well as the DataModel. It handles the actual database calls.
- **BusinessLayer**: This provides `controller classes` to handle specific tasks as specified by the underlying requirements. It requires both the InterfaceProvider and the DataModel
- **Desktop application**: This is the front-end the user will interact with

*DataModel*

```
public class cInstructor {
    public int ID {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string Email {get; private set;}
    public bool IsNewEntry {get{return ID<0;}}
    public cInstructor():this(-1,"",""){}

    public cInstructor(int theID, string theName, string theEmail)
    {
        ID = theID; Name = theName; Email = theEmail;
    }

    public void Update(cInstructor that)
    {
        Name = that.Name; Email = that.Email;
    }
}
```

*InterfaceProvider*

```
public interface IInstructorRepository {
    cInstructor GetByID(int theID);
    void Save(cInstructor theInstructor);
    void Update(cInstructor theInstructor);
    IEnumerable<cInstructor> GetList();
}

public interface IDataRepository {
    IInstructorRepository InstructorRepository;
}
```

*DataRepositoryMySQL*

```
public class cInstructorRepository : IInstructorRepository {
    private string ConnectionString;
    public cInstructorRepository(string theConnectionString) {ConnectionString = theConnectionString;}
    public cInstructor GetByID(int theID) {
        if (theID<0) return new cInstructor(); //IDs below 0 cannot be found in the database so a new instructor is required
    // call of stored procedure...
    }
    public void Save(cInstructor theInstructor) {
    // call of stored procedure...
    }
    public void Update(cInstructor theInstructor) {
    // call of stored procedure...
    }
    public IEnumerable<cInstructor> GetList() {
    // call of stored procedure...
    }
}

public class cRepositoryMySQL : IDataRepository {
    private string ConnectionString;
    public IInstructorRepository InstructorRepository {get; private set;}
    public cRepositoryMySQL(string theConnectionString) {
        ConnectionString = theConnectionString;
        InstructorRepository = new cInstructorRepository(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

*BusinessLayer*

```
public class cInstructorController {
    private IDataRepository Repository;
    public cInstructor Instructor {get; private set;}
    public cInstructorController(IDataRepository theRepository):this(theRepository, new cIntructor()) {}
    public cInstructorController(IDataRepository theRepository, cInstructor theInstructor) {
        Repository = theRepository;
        Instructor = theInstructor;
    }
    public void SaveInstructor() {
        if(Instructor.IsNewEntry) SaveNew();
        else Update();
    }
    private void SaveNew() {
        Repository.InstructorRepository.Save(Instructor);
    }
    private void Update() {
        Repository.InstructorRepository.Update(Instructor);
    }
}
```

And finally we get to the application itself. For simplicity's sake it consists only of a form displaying a combobox with all instructors from the Database (never mind the exact Combobox item shenannigans) which then fills some textboxes upon selectedIndexChanged. Any changes made to the textboxes can be saved to the database by means of a save button.

*Desktop application*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cRepositoryMySQL Repo = new cRepositoryMySQL("My fancy connection string");
        frm_InstructorManagement f = new frm_InstructorManagement(Repo);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}

partial class frm_InstructorManagement {
    private IDataRepository Repository;
    private cInstructorController InstructorController;
    private List<cInstructorComboboxItem> allInstructors;
    public frm_InstructorManager(IDataRepository theRepository) {
        Repository = theRepository;
        InitializeComponents();
        allInstructors = new List<cInstructor>();
        allInstructors.Add(new cInstructor()); //Add empty instructor as proxy for "Add new entry"
        allInstructors.AddRange(Repository.InstructorRepository.GetList().Select(x=>new cInstructorComboboxItem(x));
        cmb_Instructors.DataSource = allInstructors;
        cmb_Instructors.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    private void cmb_Instructors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormFromObject(Repository.InstructorRepository.GetByID(allInstructors[cmb_Instructors.SelectedIndex].Value.ID)); //In reality the combobox item holds just a reduced dataset of the instructor to keep the whole list and its querying more lightweight
    }

    private void FormFromObject(cInstructor theInstructor)
    {
        InstructorController = new cInstructorController(Repository, theInstructor);
        if (InstructorController.Instructor != null) //Safeguard against null returned from database
        {
            txt_Email.Text = InstructorController.Instructor.Email;
            txt_Name.Text = InstructorController.Instructor.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while loading instructor"); //Probably will extend the Controller to return an object describing the result of the operation
            //TODO: Disable controls
        }
    }
    private cInstructor ObjectFromForm() {
        return new cInstructor(InstructorController.Instructor.ID,txt_Name.Text,txt_Email.Text);
    }
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InstructorController.Instructor.Update(ObjectFromForm());
        InstructorController.SaveInstructor();
    }
}
```

Phew! If you have made it this far: Congratulations!

Obviously the final application will do a tad more, but I think the shown part is sufficient to illustrate what I want to implement.

I am confident that I have understood what the Repository pattern tries to achieve and have implemented it correctly by using the three libraries *DataModel*, *InterfaceProvider* and *DataRepositoryMySQL*. And I quite like what I have done, I have the feeling it will be easy to use and has the added bonus of seperating concerns nicely.

What I am not sure about is the layout of the *BusinessLayer* and its usage in the application. The creation of a `ControllerObject` for a specific set of operations on an entity from the DataModel sort of makes sense, because it is just another level of abstraction and it keeps the dependency injection away from my actual data objects. I could use this controller in a desktop application where the app uses a UserForm to display the data and allow interaction, while at the same time using it in a webpage to provide the exact same functionality. (This is probably never going to happen at least for this specific scenario, but learning and stuff...)

The usage inside the application however seems a bit higgledy-piggledy. On the one hand I use the controller for any meaningfiul interaction with an object like saving (and that object resides inside of the controller) but at the same time I manipulate the object itself (by doing `InstructorController.Instructor.Update(ObjectFromForm());`). Setting the actual object `private` inside the controller and duplicating the `public void Update(cInstructor)` would get me around that, but then I would have to figure out a way to get at all the relevant properties of the object to fill the GUI. And the easiest way to do that would be to make the object publicly accessible from the controller.

**So it boils down to the question if this is how it is usually done.**

Any pointers regarding the interaction of the presentation layer and the business layer are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pointers regarding the interaction of the presentation layer and the business layer`  => is that all you are interested in, the interaction of two abstract layers? Show us your interaction code. That will give further insight into the design and your intentions.

Comment: I put in a call to the British Museum of Anthropology in London. They might be able to decipher the hieroglyphics. Naming exposes implementation, that's a kind of leaky abstraction: `cInstructorController`. Then underscores: `cmb_Instructors_SelectedIndexChanged`. Many are pure Implementation Oriented (IO) regardless of hierogliphication: `FormFromObject`  which returns void; two mysteries in one! The overall effect obscures the API to say too little about the business solution at hand.

Comment: `it boils down to the question if this is how it is usually done`  => Asking general "best practices" questions is discouraged in CodeReview. The context of the working code is everything. If one can say anything about design patterns generally: "It is a reasonable suggestion"

Comment: _"So it boils down to the question if this is how it is usually done."_ It would be significantly more time efficient to read resources on that topic, as opposed to iteratively taking stabs at it and having it reviewed. You put a lot of thought into this but you're effectively asking us to feed you information that is already amply available through your preferred search engine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question on general development practice. The posted code is only used as an example of OP's current understanding, reviewing it is not the primary focus here.

Comment: @radarbob: Nah, I checked with the British Museum, they said I could play with their hyroglyphs ;) That Part is (partly auto generated) UI-Code, so of course FormFromObject returns nothing, because it sets the properties of the controls on the form. But I fear you and Flater are right and I put the question in the wrong place. Do you think Stackoverflow would be a better place?

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: Do not preface class names with "c". Be consistent when using brackets. Why do you preface parameter names with "the"? Please do not pass the connection string around via constructors, that is why configuration classes exist. Why do you call stored procedures for the simplest of actions? Please [learn about Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/) or other ORMs. And once you use ORMs, chances are a repository will be overkill (unless you need to write tests and want to abstract away that layer).